# STI: Unknown attribute in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem.
I have model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

model Contractor which inherited from User

```
class Contractor < User
  has_many :contractorEs
  has_many :customers
end
```

and model Customer which inherited from User

```
class Customer < User
  belongs_to :contractor
  has_many :customer_es
end
```

In my Customers table I have column "contractor_id".
Then I `rails c` and type:

```
c = Contractor.first
c.customers.build
```

And `unknown attribute: contractor_id` occurred. Then I type:

```
customer = Customer.new
```

and have:

```
<Customer id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, address: nil, country: nil, zip: nil, city: nil, phone: nil, company_name: nil, signature: nil, type: "Customer", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, v_token: nil, password_digest: nil, u_token: nil, email: nil, state: "new">
```

but there is no `contractor_id` in the list.
How to solve it? I'm using rails 4 and ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Create a migration and add it to your database

```
rails g migration AddContractorIdToUsers contractor_id:integer

rake db:migrate
```

Then proceed to setup the self-referential relationship[Self referential Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins)

Comment: I already have contractor_id in my customers table. It's added on create model.

Comment: We don't see it in the in your Customer.new code which is just a user row in the db. See the 2nd answer. You do not have a contractor_id column.

Comment: you need to add a separate column for the self-referential, you can't rely just on the primary keys, you need a foreign key and setup the attributes in the associations.

Comment: @NikitaKissMe you said "customers table" but since this is STI I assume you meant "users" table. You don't have multiple tables, right?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I know of for this error is because the `users` table does not have a `contractor_id` column. That's why you're not seeing it in the attribute list for Customer. Double check the table and generate a migration to add this column if it does not exist.